# Ant xmlvalidate cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'topic'

Tags: ant, xsd-validation

I've made an xsd that represent a restriction of docbook topic. Here is a basic xml example of that. The restriction should be valid within docbook namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" 
    xml:id="TT_LONDON002-003CONTEN" role="imprint">
    <title>title</title>
</topic>
```

The top of the xsd restriction looks like the following. In oxygen the xml validates nicely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           targetNamespace="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" 
           xmlns:docbook="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" 
           xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
             schemaLocation="xlink.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
             schemaLocation="xml.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="topic">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" 
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                    ref="docbook:title"/>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element ref="docbook:mediaobject"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" 
                      maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                      ref="docbook:para"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
```

However I'm trying to write the following ant script to validate a whole directory.

I get error output: **cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'topic'.**

I've been searching online but can't find the solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="dist" name="ANTProject">
 <target name="dist">

  <property name="xmlDir" value="../xml/"/>


  <pathconvert dirsep="/" property="xsd.file">
   <path>
    <pathelement location="../xsd/topic.xsd"/>
   </path>
  </pathconvert>


  <xmlvalidate lenient="true" 
               failonerror="false" 
               warn="true" 
               classname="org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser" 
               classpath="../../lib/xercesImpl.jar">
   <fileset dir="${xmlDir}" includes="**/*.xml"/>
   <attribute name="http://xml.org/sax/features/validation" 
              value="true"/>
   <attribute name="http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces" 
              value="true"/>
   <attribute name="http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema" 
              value="true"/>  
   <property name="http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-schemaLocation" 
             value="${xsd.file}"/>
  </xmlvalidate>

 </target>
</project>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Conteh

Comment: Are you certain that Xerces is successfully reading your XSD schema document?  (Try putting a syntax error in it and seeing if your error message changes.)  I notice that the `xsd.file` property is set using a relative path; how confident are you that you know what counts as the base path for resolving that relative path?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen your right, I'm not able to get it to find the xsd even If I hard code the directory path. I notice however it will find the schema using the external-noNamespaceSchemaLocation property. However then I get the message "TargetNamespace.2: Expecting no namespace, but the schema document has a target namespace of '[http://docbook.org/ns/docbook]'."
 I wonder now if external-schemaLocation needs to be a URI.